# Why does patching a classmethod on a base class effect subclasses?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, patch

I ran into a problem with patching a `classmethod` on a base-class. The problem is that patching the base-class effects calling the classmethod on a subclass.

I expect the output of this to produce `["foo", "bar"]` however with the `mocker.spy(Foo, "wrapper")` called before calling the classmethod the result is `["foo", "foo"]`.

What is happening here?

```py
def test_patching_parent_class(mocker):
    """
    pip install pytest pytest-mock
    """
    calls = []

    class Foo:
        def func2(self):
            calls.append("foo")

        @classmethod
        def wrapper(cls):
            cls().func2()

    class Bar(Foo):
        def func2(self):
            calls.append("bar")

    # Remove this line it will produce the expected result
    spy = mocker.spy(Foo, "wrapper")
    Foo.wrapper()
    Bar.wrapper()
    assert calls == ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: There is no method `Bar.wrapper`.  When you call `Bar.wrapper()` python goes up the class hierarchy until it finds a method with that name in the class hierarchy, in this case `Foo.wrapper`.   You've changed `Foo.wrapper`, but the same process still happens.

Comment: @FrankYellin Yeah, but `calls` should still just be `["foo", "bar"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `pytest_mock.MockFixture.spy`. [Here is a link to the source](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock/blob/65b40f421db7ff67270123168de3fde5f84b65f8/src/pytest_mock/plugin.py#L130):

You can see, it's basically retrieving the "method" from the object (in this case, the class `Foo`), but since `obj` is a class, `Foo`, and `name` refers to a `classmethod`, this is now a *bound method*:

```py
method = getattr(obj, name)
```

It is *bound* with `Foo`. [This is how classmethods work](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods). They act analogously to regular functions being called on an instance when they themselves are called on a class. If this were a regular function, `method` would just be the plain function (since [trying to retrieve a function attribute on a class not on an instance normally a just returns the function itself](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods)). Then, it creates a wrapper that calls that method:

```py
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    spy_obj.spy_return = None
    spy_obj.spy_exception = None
    try:
        r = method(*args, **kwargs)
    except BaseException as e:
        spy_obj.spy_exception = e
        raise
    else:
        spy_obj.spy_return = r
    return r
```

And that wrapper is what is patched with a mock object:

```py
spy_obj = self.patch.object(obj, name, side_effect=wrapped, autospec=autospec)
```

Which acts as your "spy".

But again, it is *bound* with `Foo`. So, regardless of how `wrapper` is called, its first argument is always bound with `Foo`, never `Bar`. So `cls.func2` resolves to `Foo.func2` instead of `Bar.func2`.

Comment: I don't think `pytest_mock.MockFixture.spy` is the issue. The OP's code would work if you simply replace `MockerFixture._Patcher.object` with `unittest.mock.patch.object` (see [demo](https://replit.com/@blhsing1/DodgerblueReasonableSphere)). Since `MockerFixture._Patcher.object` is just a thin wrapper around `unittest.mock._patch_object`, this suggests that it's something that the wrapper does that causes the bug, which I have yet to figure out, but `pytest_mock.MockFixture.spy` is definitely not the issue here.

Comment: Then why is `side_effect=wrapped` not an issue when `unittest.mock.patch.object` is used in place of `MockerFixture._Patcher.object`?

Comment: @blhsing if I set a break-point, then `Foo.wrapper` and `Bar.wrapper` no longer return a `Mock` object, can't figure out why yet. So, they are no longer being "spied" on.

Comment: Right, my breakpoints revealed as much. Can't see why yet myself either. Good head scratcher.

Comment: Ah, because `unittest.mock.patch.object` returns a `_patch` object while `MockerFixture._Patcher.object` returns a `Mock` object (returned by calling the `start` method of the `_patch` object) so the API isn't 100% compatible. Still, that difference affects only the returning value of `spy` and should not affect the behavior of `Bar.wrapper`.

Comment: Ah, because the `_patch` object returned by `unittest.mock.patch.object` never got `start`ed so `Bar.wrapper` remains bound to `Bar` and has not become a `Mock` object. The incompatibility between the two implementations of `patch.object` threw me off. Your answer is therefore spot on. +1